# シェルコマンドで行数と列数の変形

Tags: shellscript, shell

test.csv というファイルがあり任意の列数のデータへ加工をしたいです。

```
$cat test.csv
a
b
c
d
```

例として2列に変形した場合、下記のような書式へ変形をしたいです。

```
a b
c d
```

その際どのようなシェルコマンドを利用することで実現ができるでしょうか

Comment: `xargs -n 2 < test.csv` などとしても良いかと。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

私なら`awk`を使います。`if(NR % 2)`の数字を変えれば任意の列数で改行されます。

```
$ awk '{ if(NR % 2) { printf "%s ", $1 } else { printf "%s\n", $1 } }' test.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

sed での別解を書いておきます。

```
sed 'N; s/\n/ /' test.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

僕も通常であれば `xargs` を利用しますが、別解で上げておきます。

```sh
$ cat test.csv| column -c 16                                                                                      
a       c
b       d
```

2カラム表示に加えて整形してくれます。

Answer (score 2):

`cat test.csv | paste - -`
や
`printf "%s %s\n"  $(cat test.csv)`
はいかがでしょうか？